# PHP "file_get_contents()" function return null

Tags: php, nginx, file-get-contents

I got a trouble when i use the function **"file_get_contents"** on CentOS and nginx .

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file = "/srv/http/php/cms/extern/ip/pc.htm";

 if (@is_file($file) === false) {// it is true;

     $result['error'] = 'no file';

 }

 if (@fopen($file, "r") === false) {  // it is true

     @fclose($htmlFilePath);

 }

$htmlContent = file_get_contents($file); // return null
```

And I open the htm file at browser and it can work.I search something in google ,then I verify the options in php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
```

and the disabled function list don't have include that;

Then i restart the nginx  and centOS .But it can't work -_-!!

Please help and tell where is the bug.Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are any contents there? You can also set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the start to see if any errors pops up.

Comment: file_get_contents function only works when you use full web url. Set url which you able to open in browser

Comment: @Janno Thanks your advice but it doesn't report any bug

Comment: @SunnySharma i am sure the url can be open and it is exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem before. I solved it by adding the encoding charset. In my case, I added the UTF-8 charset. It might be the case that the browser encodes the file but nginx and centOS not.

- Add the encoding meta tag between the head tags.

If it is not work, I would suggest to try it with a full URL too. PHP will not recognize the URL as a relative URL.